# Making section in UITableView closed(with 0 cells) after scrolling away and returning to it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a UITableView where I have section headers that can be tapped to expand or collapse the section. In my particular example each section only has one row, which is either visible (section expanded) or hidden (section collapsed). (I have a UITapGestureRecognizer on the section headers which I use to expand or collapse the sections)  here the process of my actions:

I'm tap on the section (this is UITableViewHeaderFooterView custom view) and i see the cell that appears under the section header. At this moment everything is going OK. But when i scrolling down my tableview, cell goes behind header (like in Contacts application , header is first letter of contact). And finally when i scroll enough to don't see that section with that cell on, and when i scroll up - to return to my display that section - i want to make this section automatically known that when i return(from scrolling away that section from view) to it - i want that section already was closed with 0 cells in it.

Maybe i must use -(void) prepareForReuse at my custom UITableViewHeaderFooterView, or scroll methods ? or any tableView methods?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the scroll view delegate methods and use them to check the scroll position (`contentOffset`) and / or the visible cells (`indexPathsForVisibleRows`). Once you know that you can collapse any sections that are no longer visible. You should probably use one of the scroll methods that means the scrolling has stopped (maybe `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:`) because changing the table view content size (which changing the number of rows will do) during a scroll animation could cause it to stop abruptly.